# Issue with Single quote from Controller to client side MVC page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have Serverside code that is coming from Controller method as below in ViewData.

```
 "{'Double-Click to edit':'','7C486':'7C486','7C489':'7C489','7C490':'7C490','7C491':'7C491','7C492':'7C492'}";
```

But I have to display these values into Dropdown that is in Jquery Editable Grid.
I am accessing the code from Server to Jquery as here:

```
var reasonCd = '@ViewData["ReasonCodes"].ToString()';
```

and the value is:

```
 reasonCd = '{&#39;Double-Click to edit&#39;:&#39;&#39;,&#39;7C486&#39;:&#39;7C486&#39;,&#39;7C489&#39;:&#39;7C489&#39;,&#39;7C490&#39;:&#39;7C490&#39;}';
```

Not sure why it is decoding like this.
Now I have to replace & #39; with **single quote**.

I tried this:

```
reasonCd.replace("&#39;", "'");
```

But it is erroring out.

Highly appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `Html.Raw()` method to prevent HTML encoding of the data.

`var reasonCd = '@Html.Raw(ViewData["ReasonCodes"].ToString())';`